# Does the Azure Storage Emulator support blob versioning? If so, how do I enable it?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, database-versioning, azure-storage-emulator

I am developing a C# ASP.NET Core web application for Azure. I am using the Microsoft Azure Storage Emulator for local testing: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator

I want to use blob versioning as described here:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/azure/storage/blobs/versioning-overview
- https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/azure/storage/blobs/versioning-enable?tabs=azure-cli

Is this supported by the Storage Emulator? I cannot find any description of how to enable it for the emulator, at least.

Is there any convenient way to test blob-version-related code locally?

Comment: No, latest version of storage emulator is based on storage service 2019-07-07. versioning feature of blob service is not available at that time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this feature is not enable on latest storage emulator.

Please check the [latest version of Storage Emulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator#version-510). This version don't have versioning feature.

The versioning feature of blob storage [becomes available in August 2020](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azure-blob-versioning-is-now-general-available/).

Comment: Thanks. Your wording is confusing, but from the article I understand that the Emulator only supports up to the 2019-07-07 version of the storage services, and I need storage services version 2020-08-31 (or whatever the exact date is) to get blob versioning.

Comment: Have you checked if azurite supports the feature? I've found I prefer it to Ms emulator

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Azurite seems also not support now: https://github.com/Azure/Azurite#features--key-changes-in-azurite-v3